# Ignore checkstyle exceptions in gradle builds

Tags: gradle, checkstyle, gradle-plugin

I am using Java14 features in my code. This will be possible in Checkstyle [from September 2020](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/7992#issuecomment-605986115) on. Until then, it [causes an exception](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/6615).

[Example java code](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361):

```java
switch (day) {
    case MONDAY, FRIDAY, SUNDAY -> System.out.println(6);
    case TUESDAY                -> System.out.println(7);
    case THURSDAY, SATURDAY     -> System.out.println(8);
    case WEDNESDAY              -> System.out.println(9);
}
```

I configured checkstyle not to halt on exceptions:

```xml
<property name="haltOnException" value="false"/>
```

This still leads checkstyle to fail:

```
ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /home/runner/work/jabref/jabref/src/main/java/org/jabref/logic/layout/format/AuthorAndsReplacer.java:1: Got an exception - com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: IllegalStateException occurred while parsing file /home/runner/work/jabref/jabref/src/main/java/org/jabref/logic/layout/format/AuthorAndsReplacer.java.
> Task :checkstyleMain
[ant:checkstyle]    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:105)
```

Is it possible to ignore parsing errors at checking?

**I still want to other classes to be checked**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use https://checkstyle.org/config_filefilters.html#BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter in your Checkstyle config to tell Checkstyle to not process these files at all. This will exclude all modules from being run on said files, including modules that use the Java parser and those that don't. There is no other way in Checkstyle to avoid these files from being parsed.

I don't know Gradle very well, but Checkstyle command line has `-e` and `-x` arguments to also ignore files. This results in the same type of exclusion as the above filter. If gradle can make use of Checkstyle's command line, then this is another option, but again, just duplicates the filter in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using :

```
checkstyle {
    sourceSets = []
}
```

Also you can use command line argument:

```
gradle build -x checkstyleMain
```

Comment: This seems to disable checkstyle completely. See, I have more than 100 source files and want to ignore only 2 using Java14 syntax (all the others do not)